# assertNull using JUnit fails with NullPointerException

Tags: java, junit, null

For my project one of the returns has to be null. When testing using `assertNull(Null Object here)` it fails with a `NullPointerException`.

Can someone please tell my why? I thought assertNull is supposed to test for null.

Here is part of my code.

```
public static UVI calculateUVI(double[] radiation) {
    double calculation = 0.0;
    double[] copyRad = new double[radiation.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < radiation.length; i++)
    {
        copyRad[i] = radiation[i];
        if (radiation[i] > RADIATION_MAXIMUM)
            copyRad[i] = RADIATION_MAXIMUM;

        if (radiation[i] < RADIATION_MINIMUM)
            copyRad[i] = 0.0;

        calculation += (copyRad[i] * MD_WEIGHTS[i]);
    }

    if (radiation.length != MD_WEIGHTS.length || radiation == null) {
      UVI nulled = null;
      return nulled;
    }

    calculation /= B;
    UVI result = new UVI(calculation, true);
    return result;
}
```

My test case is:

```
double[] test1 = {4., 26., 30., 17., 2.};
double[] test2 = {0., 0., 0., 0., 0.};
double[] test3 = {4., 26., 30., 100., 2.};
double[] test4 = {4., 26., 30., 200., 2.};
double[] test5 = {3.4, 0., 17., 17., 2.};
double[] test6 = {3.4, -10., 17., 17., 2.};
double[] test7 = {1.0};
double[] test8 = {};
double[] test9 = null;

UVI testOne = UVICalculator.calculateUVI(test1);
UVI testTwo = UVICalculator.calculateUVI(test2);
UVI testThree = UVICalculator.calculateUVI(test3);
UVI testFour = UVICalculator.calculateUVI(test4);
UVI testFive = UVICalculator.calculateUVI(test5);
UVI testSix = UVICalculator.calculateUVI(test6);
UVI testSeven = UVICalculator.calculateUVI(test7);
UVI testEight = UVICalculator.calculateUVI(test8);
UVI testNine= UVICalculator.calculateUVI(test9);

assertTrue(8.8956 == testOne.getValue());
assertTrue(0 == testTwo.getValue());
assertTrue(8.9952 == testThree.getValue());
assertTrue(8.9952 == testFour.getValue());
assertTrue(4.027200000000001 == testFive.getValue());
assertTrue(4.027200000000001 == testSix.getValue());
assertNull(testSeven);
assertNull(testEight);
assertNull(testNine);
```

Comment: it is not the test that fails, but your code implementation, here `double[] copyRad = new double[radiation.length];` on test9 when radiation is null; it is always a good idea to include the full stacktrace when asking questions about an exception. Welcome to stackoverflow

Comment: Thanks, yah ill add the rest of my code next time ill ask a question! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't the assert statement.

You are calling `calculateUVI(...)` with a null array when passing in array `test9`.

Since the array is null `radiation.length` is going to throw a `NullPointerException` in the method.

Since the method cannot run with a null array you could add a "Guard Clause" and simply return null immediately from the method so your test will succeed.

```
public static UVI calculateUVI(double[] radiation) {
    if(radiation == null) {
        return null;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried adding a guard but for some reason it failed the first time and now it worked. Thank you though! Solved my problem!

Comment: Realized why it failed. I had the radiation == null at the end of my if statement and not the beginning.... heh. So others passed and last failed so it kept going.